# Should training images contains single or multiple object instances?

Tags: computer-vision, multiclass-classification, object-detection, object-recognition

I'm pretty new to ML so I apologize for the potentially trivial question; I've been unable to find a clear answer to my question.

Let's imagine that I want to build a model that is able to detect sharks in images.
I put a camera in the water and hit record. I end up with thousands of images. Some of the frames depict a single shark, some depict several sharks, others depict 1 or more sharks among other objects such as fish and maybe even a random submarine.

Now, the question is: which of the images are most suitable, which should I throw away, and why?

For instance, must each individual training image contain ONE and ONLY ONE shark (each at slightly different angles, lighting, etc.)? Is an image/frame depicting several sharks OK (I imagine that would work for image classification, but not so well for object detection)? What about images that contain sharks and other objects/fish?

If someone can explain to me (even better if you have a link to a good resource), I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are building. For classification tasks, you want 1 object to exist, and to take up nearly the entire frame. For object detection tasks, either will work. Classification CNN works differently than Object Detection.

In a classification CNN, the CNN learns features and then there is a head which does the classification. A classification CNN does not tell you the location of the object because the object is the image. A classification CNN only tells you the object, which is why it doesn't make any sense to include multiple objects in the image. Only include the bounding box of 1 instance of the object.

In an object detection CNN, the CNN learns a location and a classification ID of an object. So here either multiple instances or single instances are useful to train the CNN.

One book that helped me a lot with understanding this is Advanced Deep Learning with TensorFlow 2 and Keras, Chapter 11.

Edit:

What is a "head" in "the CNN learns features and there is a head that
does the classification"?

There are 2 types of layers in a CNN: (1) convolutional layers and (2) fully-connected layers. Convolutional layers are used to extract features. Fully connected layers correlate features to an image classification.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you please clarify for me, what do you mean by `head` in "the CNN learns features and then there is a head which does the classification"?